# Listening for metadata (title) changes in Realtime API file

Tags: javascript, google-drive-realtime-api

My application uses the Realtime API to edit a custom type of file in google drive.  I would like the title displayed on the editing page to be updated if the filename is changed remotely (by a collaborator, for instance).

How can I have my client-side page listen for this sort of metadata change and react to it?

Comment: AFAIK The filename metadata is not present in the realtime document. You can load the metadata on each pageload, or if you manage all the clients you can have them insert the metadata or poke the realtime doc when the client changes the title (won't work for non-owned clients obv..).

Comment: Try to check this [Listening for Realtime events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/handle-events) documentation if it can help you on your case. It is stated here that whenever a data model object is modified, either by the local client or by another collaborator, an event describing the change is fired.

Comment: Also, all changes to collaborative objects, such as modifying a string, collection, or custom type, emit events. Because changes can originate from either the local application or a remote collaborator, it is important that applications properly listen for and respond to these events to keep the view in sync with the model. Just check the link above for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks KENdi, but Grant Watters is right that the title is not part of the realtime document itself; it is in the Google Drive metadata.  So it doesn't emit events the way that changes to collaborative objects do.  Grant - clever idea, but the title can be changed outside of my control (eg, on Google Drive page)